# Closed form for $\int \frac{1}{x^7 -1} dx$?

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals, closed-form

I want to calculate:

$$\int \frac{1}{x^7 -1} dx$$

Since $\displaystyle \frac{1}{x^7 -1}  = - \sum_{i=0}^\infty x^{7i} $, we have $\displaystyle(-x)\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{x^{7i}}{7i +1} $.

Is there another solution? That is, can this integral be written in terms of elementary functions?

Comment: [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+%281%2F%28x%5E7+-+1%29%29) hints that it would be complicated, although it's known to not always simplify, so it's possible there is a simpler solution out there.

Comment: Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/title-and-latex).

Comment: Okay. I will not write titles consisting only of math expressions.

Comment: Mathematica tells us $\int\frac{1}{x^n-1}\mathrm d x=-x\cdot{}_2F_1(1,b,1+b,x^n)$ with $b=\tfrac{1}{n}$. The Pochhammer symbols cancel for the most part and the $i^\text{th}$ coefficient reduces to your $\frac{1}{i\cdot n+1}$. If your're interested in specific integral bounds, maybe one can use relations of ${}_2F_1$, but otherwise this seems to be as good as it gets.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Factorise $x^{7}-1$ and use partial fractions - I do not expect your answer to be nice. You should get 3 unfactorable quadratics which will contribute $\tan^{-1}$ terms, and one factor $x-1$ which will give some multiple of $\ln(x-1)$.

To perform the actual factorisation, note that the roots of $x^{7}=1$ are $e^{\frac{2ni\pi}{7}}=\cos(2n\pi/7)+i\sin(2n\pi/7)$ for, say, $n\in\{-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3\}$. Thus we can factorise as follows:
$$x^{7}-1=(x-e^{-6i\pi/7})(x-e^{-4i\pi/7})(x-e^{-2i\pi/7})(x-1)(x-e^{2i\pi/7})(x-e^{4i\pi/7})(x-e^{6i\pi/7})$$
Now note that $(x-e^{i\theta})(x-e^{-i\theta})=x^{2}-(e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta})x+1=x^{2}-2x\cos\theta+1$ is a real-valued quadratic, and hence if we group the linear complex factors into pairs like this, we can get 3 real quadratics as we wanted. The factorisation becomes
$$x^{7}-1=(x^{2}-2c_{1}x+1)(x^{2}-2c_{2}x+1)(x^{2}-2c_{3}x+1)(x-1)$$
where $c_{k}=\cos(2k\pi/7)$.
Now try partial fractions - you need to find constants $A_{1}\ldots A_{7}$ such that
$$\frac{1}{x^{7}-1}=\frac{A_{1}x+A_{2}}{x^{2}-2c_{1}x+1}+\frac{A_{3}x+A_{4}}{x^{2}-2c_{2}x+1}+\frac{A_{5}x+A_{6}}{x^{2}-2c_{3}x+1}+\frac{A_{7}}{x-1}$$
By multiplying by each factor, you can get a set of seven linear equations for your seven constants, which you can solve by any method you choose. This will be very unpleasant. Integrating the last term is trivial (simply $A_{7}\ln(x-1)$) and the quadratic terms are less so. Taking the first term as an example, note $$x^{2}-2c_{1}x+1=(x-c_{1})^{2}+(1-c_{1}^{2})=(1-c_{1}^{2})\left[\left(\frac{x-c_{1}}{\sqrt{1-c_{1}^{2}}}\right)^{2}+1\right]$$
So, making the substution $u=\frac{x-c_{1}}{\sqrt{1-c_{1}^{2}}}$ will give you some terms of the form $\frac{2au+b}{u^{2}+1}$ which trivially integrates to $a\ln(u^{2}+1)+b\tan^{-1}(u)$. The arithemtic of finding these constants is left as an exercise for you.

Comment: I cannot understand. $x^7-1 = (x-1)(x^6+x^5+ ... + x+1)$

Comment: $x^{6}+x^{5}+\ldots+x+1$ factorises further, by the fundamental theorem of algebra.

Comment: @HeeKwonLee I have completed my answer; hopefully you find it helpful.

Comment: Thank you. Since you factorize $x^7-1$, as like $x^2-2c_ix +1$, I can grab solving way.

Answer (score 0):

Allowing complex numbers, we can write
$$
\int \frac{dx}{x^7-1} = \frac{1}{7}\left(\log(x-1) + \sum_{k=1}^6 \exp(i 2\pi k/7) \log\big(x-\exp(i 2 \pi k/7)\big)\right) + C .
$$

Comment: I think that it is more refined form. You mean : $$\frac{1}{x^7-1} = \frac{1}{7} \sum_{k=0}^6 \frac{\omega^k}{x-\omega^k},\ \omega = \exp\ (2\pi i/7) $$

Answer (score 0):

Let u=x^2 and solve using u substitution.

=> 1/6 ln((x^6-1)/x^6)

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).